# Kotlin data class create dynamically json of its fields using GSON

Tags: serialization, kotlin, constructor, android, gson

I have a data class like this:

```
data class TestModel(
     val id: Int, 
     val description: String, 
     val picture: String)
```

If I create JSON from this data class using GSON and it generates a result like this

```
{"id":1,"description":"Test", "picture": "picturePath"}
```

What to do if I need the following JSON from my data class:

```
{"id":1, "description":"Test"}
```

And other times:

```
`{"id":1, "picture": "picturePath"}
```

`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: given your use of the GSON tag, I added GSON to the title and text to make it clear that this was a GSON specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem with writing custom adapter and with optional types:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter

data class TestModel(
    val id: Int,
    val description: String? = "",
    val picture: String? = "")

class TesModelTypeAdapter : TypeAdapter<TestModel>() {
    override fun read(reader: JsonReader?): TestModel {
        var id: Int? = null
        var picture: String? = null
        var description: String? = null

        reader?.beginObject()
        while (reader?.hasNext() == true) {
            val name = reader.nextName()

            if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                reader.nextNull()
                continue
            }

            when (name) {
                "id" -> id = reader.nextInt()
                "picture" -> picture = reader.nextString()
                "description" -> description = reader.nextString()
            }
        }
        reader?.endObject()

        return when {
            !picture.isNullOrBlank() && description.isNullOrBlank() -> TestModel(id = id ?: 0, picture = picture)
            !description.isNullOrBlank() && picture.isNullOrBlank() -> TestModel(id = id ?: 0, description = description)
            else -> TestModel(id ?: 0, picture, description)
        }
    }

    override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: TestModel?) {
        out?.apply {
            beginObject()

            value?.let {
                when {
                    !it.picture.isNullOrBlank() && it.description.isNullOrBlank() -> {
                        name("id").value(it.id)
                    name("picture").value(it.picture)
                    }
                    !it.description.isNullOrBlank() && it.picture.isNullOrBlank() -> {
                        name("id").value(it.id)
                    name("description").value(it.description)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        name("id").value(it.id)
                        name("picture").value(it.picture)
                    name("description").value(it.description)
                    }
                }
            }

            endObject()
        }
    }
}

class App {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val tm = TestModel(12, description = "Hello desc")
            val tm2 = TestModel(23, picture = "https://www.pexels.com/photo/daylight-forest-glossy-lake-443446/")
            val tm3 = TestModel(12, "Hello desc", "https://www.pexels.com/photo/daylight-forest-glossy-lake-443446/")

            val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(TestModel::class.java, TesModelTypeAdapter()).create()

            System.out.println(gson.toJson(tm))
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(tm2))
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(tm3))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is actually a way to ignore fields, that are not marked via `@Exposed` annotation. In order for this to work, special configuration should be used when instantiating `Gson`. [Here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-how-to-ignore-fields-with-expose) is how you can to this.

Easy way is to mark the field as `@Transient`. Then it would not be either serialized and deserialized.

Comment: I edited my question Expose and Transient are ignoring my field always, i need to create dynamically json

Comment: Have you considered a variant of manual implementation of `JsonSerializer` then? https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html

Comment: Thank you for yr quick reply. I think, It is a last chance, but i need easy way from developers who have faced already?

Comment: For example in Java, i create multiple constructor then generate gson with constructor fields which i wanted.

Comment: It's the same bytecode received from Kotlin source code after compilation as Java's...
Writing secondary constructors didn't help?

Comment: is it possible to create two constructor with the same fields i mean ```constructor(id: Int, description: String): this(description)
    constructor(id: Int, picture: String): this(picture)
```?

Comment: Not with the same signature, of course. But maybe `typealias` (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) could help (I'm not sure but it is a thing to consider).

Answer (score 1):

I want to give you alternative ways without manually serialization/deserialization.

```
data class TestModel(
    val id: Int,
    val description: String? = null,
    val picture: String? = null)
```

When you create json from data class

```
val params = TestModel(id = 1, description = "custom text")
```

or

```
val params = TestModel(id = 1, picture = "picture path")
```

> If one of them field is null of data class GSON skips that field
>   automatically.